# "House," as a verb to mean "steal" esp. when related to food?

Tags: meaning

In episode three of [season two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Think_You_Should_Leave_with_Tim_Robinson#Season_2_(2021)) of [I Think You Should Leave with Tim Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Think_You_Should_Leave_with_Tim_Robinson) there is a skit where Tim Robinson's character has his burger taken from him at dinner.

The character that did it described his actions as:

> [image]

In text form:

> That I housed Dylan's burger.

He then goes on to threaten his dinner party that he won't do something bad

> [image]

Text:

> Unless I hear the story of me housing Dylan's burger

Where does this use of "house" come from?

Comment: Is that house pronounced like the noun for a building or house pronounced like the verb meaning to provide someone or something with accomodation?

Comment: @BoldBen I would say more like the verb.

Comment: I've seen it once or twice in credible literature, but I suspect it's a hair archaic.

Comment: Could it be hosed (slaughtered, massacred, swindled, pissed on)?

Comment: It's slang for eat up, gobble up. The burger is now housed in his stomach.

Answer (score 3):

In this sketch, "house" is being used in an idiomatic sense which normally means "defeat", or sometimes "upstage". In context, it refers to how the professor ate Dylan's burger quickly and aggressively.

This usage is chiefly seen in the context of organized sports. It refers to such things as a particularly quick or overwhelming defeat, a situation in which one party is obviously outmatched, or an exceptional competitive performance.

For example, [Pat Forde of *Sports Illustrated*, writing in August 2021](https://www.si.com/college/2021/08/29/forde-yard-dash-coaches-week-one-tests-chip-kelly-ed-orgeron), describes a 41 to 14 loss as

> *[college football coach Brady]* Hoke's Michigan squad got housed by Alabama to start his second season.

This meaning has been in use for at least a decade. In another example from a [*Sports Illustrated* article, published in 2011](https://www.si.com/nfl/2011/11/28/break-it-down-how-patrick-peterson-and-devin-hester-do-it), a play in an NFL game is described as

> *[Arizona Cardinals cornerback Patrick]* Peterson housed his fourth punt return of the year Sunday against St. Louis, tying the league's single-season mark.

Comment: These are interesting examples. The punt return example from 2011, however, seems to be framed as a way of reducing ""took it [the football] to the house [that is, to the end zone]" as a single-word verb. "Take it to the house" has been in use for at least two decades. For example, [_The Coverage of Interscholastic Sports_](https://books.google.com/books?id=ku_yAAAAMAAJ&q=%22took+it+to+the+house%22+football&dq=%22took+it+to+the+house%22+football&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFnabAh-byAhUnFjQIHfprBCc4ChDoATAAegQIBBAC) (2001) lists "He took it to the house" as a cliche.

Comment: @SvenYargs Interesting - is that possibly the etymology of the current, more general use of the word? I certainly have no personal awareness of it being used before the 00s.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathon Green, *Chambers Slang Dictionary* (2008) says that *house* in the relevant sense goes back to the 1980s:

> **house** v<sup>2</sup> {[from] *house* S[tandard E[nglish], to take into a house} **1** {1980s+} (*US black/rap music*) to take for oneself, to steal. **2** (1990s+) (*US black*) to go, to come or move towards. **3** (1990s+) (*US teen*) to give, to take or bring. **4** see GROUND *v* [going back to the 1950s, "(*orig. US*) (*also* **house**) to restrict someone, usu. an errant teenager, from enjoying their regular social life as a punishment for some real or imagined misdemeanour; usu. as *grounded*"].

Green distinguishes this set of meanings from two other forms of *house* as a verb in US slang:

> **house** v<sup>1</sup> {abbr. of roughhouse v.} **1** {1980s} (*US*) to outdo, to defeat. **2** {1990s+} (*US*) to attach someone violently. **3** {1990s+} (*US black*) to take over, to exert one's authority.

and:

> **house** v<sup>3</sup> {? SE *bring down the house*} {1980s+} (*US black/rap music*) to excite and impress an audience.

With regard to the posted question, it seems fairly clear from the context that the meaning of *housed* as used in the video clip is "to take for oneself, to steal"; and if Green is correct, the usage arose in U.S. Black slang during the 1980s from the notion of taking something into a house in order to hide or possess it there.

I found two additional reference works—one from 1994 and the other from 2006 that have relevant entries for *house* as a verb. Geneva Smitherman, *Black Talk: Words and Phrases from the Hood to the Amen Corner* (1994) has this entry for *house*:

> **HOUSE** 1) to take something from somebody; to take over, exert one's power. 2) See CLOWN ["To ridicule, humiliate. Also *house*."].

Randy Kearse, *Street Talk* (2006) asserts that the usage is primarily "east coast slang":

> "{to} **house** {someone} v. (e. ciast sl.) old school | 1. to take someone's possessions by force, intimidation, or through manipulation; to bully someone out of something. ... *ex: "I can't believe you let 'em house you."*

These entries are consistent with Green's in terms of origin and meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It's used as slang for eating a lot of food pretty commonly.
https://www.reddit.com/r/AskAnAmerican/comments/lhzn0u/house_meaning_eat_a_lot_of/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/426986)